# Get-Location with :\

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to grab the current drive letter of the CD Drive and append `:\` to it.

I was thinking something like

```
$test = (get-location).drive.name
$test2 = ":\"
$test = $test + $test2
```

Then, `$test` will equal `p:\`

This however doesn't seem very efficient, is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
(get-location).drive.root
```

Comment: Ahh yes...that was dumb of me

Comment: @aphoria 10 minute wait time.

Comment: @JMeterX Ahhh. Sorry about that. :) I see so many answers go unaccepted, even where the OP comments and says it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That's all true if you are already located in the cd drive. Here's an alternative way:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_CDRomDrive).Drive+'\'
```